# How do I define a conditional function using sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I want to be able to define an expression which takes all the values of variable where it is defined and evaluates the expression as **0** when it is not defined.
Similar to this: -

```
    import numpy as np
    import sympy as sp

    def expr(k1, k2):
        x, y =sp.symbols('x y')
        if x == k1 :
            fn = 0
        else:
            fn = np.divide(1,(x-k1)*(y-k2))
        return fn, x, y

    f,x, y = expr(1,2)
    print(f)
    fx = f.subs({x:1,y:4})
    print(fx)
```

So how is the equality or conditionality going to be checked once the function has been defined?

fn = 1/ (x-1)(y-2); How to set it as 0 for x=1 or y=2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a function inside your function and then return it. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def expr(k1, k2):
    x, y =sp.symbols('x y')
    def fn(x, y):
        if x==k1:
            return 0
        else:
            return np.divide(1, (x-k1)*(y-k2))
    return fn, x, y


f, x, y = expr(1, 2)
print(f(x, y))
print(f(1, 4))
```

**EDIT:**

Here is one way to use `sp.lambdify` as asked in the comments:

```
x_dot = 1 / ((x - 1) * (y - 2))
f = lambda a, b : 0 if a==1 or b==2 else sp.lambdify((x,y), xdot, "numpy")(a,b)
```

Another option is to use `sp.subs`

```
f = lambda a, b: 0 if a==1 or b==2 else float(x_dot.subs({x:a, y:b}))
```

Comment: What if I don't know the value of x while defining? I mean I really want to define it externally.

Comment: @Manish - `x` is not defined when you call `expr`. It is a parameter in the returning function. Only `k1` and `k2` are defined. Try the code and you'll see.

Comment: Sorry to be so pestering, The code u have given is working great, I wanted if we can have like an expression x_dot = 1/(x-1)(y-2); and use f1 = sp.lambdify((x,y), x_dot, "numpy") and then u =f1(1,2) and obtain 0 for that.

Comment: See some additional suggestions in the answer above.

Answer (score 22):

If you want a symbolic function, use `Piecewise`

```
expr = Piecewise((0, Eq(x, k1)), (1/(x - k1)/(y - k2), True))
```

If you later want to evaluate this expression on numeric values, you should convert it to a numeric function with `lambdify`

```
f = lambdify((x, y, k1, k2), expr, 'numpy')
```

I do not recommend trying to mix NumPy and SymPy functions, as that generally won't work. NumPy functions don't know how to work with SymPy expressions and SymPy functions don't know how to work with NumPy arrays. The better way is to create the symbolic expression with SymPy, manipulate it however you need, then use `lambdify` to convert it to a NumPy function.

Comment: The docs are here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise