# Sympify "<" does not return boolean in custom function?

Tags: python, sympy

**Summary**

My self-written if-then-else conditional for sympy does not work for some Booleans.

**Code**
(Note: Piecewise is not an option for me, proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858444/5626139)

```
from sympy import Function

class ifte(Function):
    nargs = 3

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b, c):
        if a > 0:
            return b
        else:
            return c
```

Which works partially, for example with these three booleans:

```
>>> print(ifte('1+2 and True and 1 != 2', 'b', 'c'))
b
```

**Problem**

Why does the line with 0<1 evaluate correctly?

```
>>> print(ifte('0==1', 'b', 'c'))
b
>>> print(ifte('0<1', 'b', 'c'))
TypeError: 
A Boolean argument can only be used in Eq and Ne; all other
relationals expect real expressions.
```

All the operators in the if-condition usually evaluate to boolean.

- Why does this not work for <, >, <=, >= ?
- Is there a solution to this?
- How can I be sure if other statements also end up as exception?

Comment: Would the `ITE` function work for you? `ITE(0<1, b, c) -> b`

Comment: I was considering `ITE`, unfortunately all ITE-args must be Booleans (not only the condition). I need all types of expressions as b or c.

Comment: If `b` and `c` are Symbols, that works fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is triggered during the `if`:

```py
from sympy import Function

class ifte(Function):
    nargs = 3

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b, c):
        if a > 0:  # <-- PROBLEM HERE
            return b
        else:
            return c
```

and it is related to the `type` that `a` gets.
Since this depends on the expression in `a`, you observe different behaviors for different expression.
In particular, for some values of `a`, this gets to be `sympy.logic.boolalg.*`.
If that is the case, then the `__gt__` method (which is called when the `>` operator is used) is not defined and you get the error you observe.
For some other values, this gets to be a simple `bool`, for which the `__gt__` method is defined and the code works the way you expect.

To solve the issue, simply remove the `> 0` comparison, i.e.

```py
from sympy import Function

class ifte(Function):
    nargs = 3

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b, c):
        if a:
            return b
        else:
            return c
```

or, even more simply:

```py
from sympy import Function

class ifte(Function):
    nargs = 3

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, a, b, c):
        return b if a else c
```

```py
print(ifte('1+2 and True and 1 != 2', 'b', 'c'))
# b
print(ifte('1==0', 'b', 'c'))
# c
print(ifte('1>0', 'b', 'c'))
# b
print(ifte('1<0', 'b', 'c'))
# c
```

Note that the error message you get depends a bit on the SymPy version you have, but the principle is the same.
For example, in version `1.1.1` I get:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'BooleanTrue' and 'int'